# Update Excel sheets from SQL Server 2005 linked servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, linked-server

I use SQL Server linked servers to connect to Excel 2003 multiple tabs workbook. After connected, I have not problem to use select statement like:

```
select * FROM OPENQUERY(TEST, 'select * from [fist day$]')
```

but I can not use normal delete and insert statement. I want to delete data from first row and insert one row of data into the last row to the excel spreadsheet.

I use:

```
delete top(1) FROM OPENQUERY(TEST, 'select * from [first day$]')
```

and I get "

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "TEST"
>   returned message "Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by
>   this ISAM.".
>   Msg 7345, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "TEST" could not delete
>   from table "select * from [first day$]". There was a recoverable,
>   provider-specific error, such as an RPC failure."

Can someone help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Excerpt:
... However, you cannot:

1. Delete an entire record at once ... You can only delete a record by blanking out the contents of each individual field
2. Delete the value in a cell containing an Excel formula
3. You cannot delete the empty spreadsheet row(s) in which the deleted data was located